# Calling base constructor in body of derived class' constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I have this base class:

```
class BaseException
{
public:
    BaseException(string _message)
    {
        m_message = _message;
    }

    string GetErrorMessage() const
    {
        return m_message;
    }

protected:
    string m_message;
};
```

and this derived class

```
class Win32Exception : public BaseException
{
public:
    Win32Exception(string operation, int errCode, string sAdditionalInfo = "")
    {
        string message = "";
        message += "Operation \"" + operation + "\" failed with error code ";
        message += std::to_string(errCode);

        if (!sAdditionalInfo.empty())
            message += "\nAdditional info: " + sAdditionalInfo;

        BaseException(message);
    }
};
```

The compiler gives me the following error:

error C2512: 'BaseException' : no appropriate default constructor available

I know I could make a really long line constructing the message that would be passed to the base class in the initializer list but it seems more elegant this way.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are not "calling base constructor", you are creating a temporary `BaseException` object (that is immediately destroyed again).

Comment: Trying to convert Java to C++?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put the same things in another way:

```
class Win32Exception : public BaseException
{
    static string buildMessage(string operation, int errCode, string
                              sAdditionalInfo)
    {
        string message ;
        message += "Operation \"" + operation + "\" failed with error code ";
        message += std::to_string(errCode);

        if (!sAdditionalInfo.empty())
            message += "\nAdditional info: " + sAdditionalInfo;
        return message;
    }
public:
    Win32Exception(string operation, int errCode, string sAdditionalInfo = "") :
         BaseException(buildMessage(operation, errCode, sAdditionalInfo )
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: @BoPersson like this?

Comment: You missed a parenthesis when calling the base constructor :)

Comment: Why didn't you show your `BaseException` class? Is your `BaseException` inheriting from `std::exception`?

Comment: no, it's just a simple class that has a string message and a getter for it. It does not inherit from std::Exception.

Answer (score 3):

You have to do the "construction" of the base class in the *[member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)* of the constructor, but not to "call" the constructor of the base class in the body of the constructor of the derived class.

This means, instead of

```
Win32Exception(string operation, int errCode, string sAdditionalInfo = "")
{
    .....
    BaseException(message);
}
```

you have to

```
Win32Exception(string operation, int errCode, string sAdditionalInfo = "")
   : BaseException("")
{
    .....
}
```

The error message

> error C2512: 'BaseException' : no appropriate default constructor available

means, that you did not define a construction of the base class `BaseException` in the member initializer list, but `BaseException` has no default constructor.
 Said in simple words, the compiler didn't know what to do, because it was not specified how the base class should be constructed.

```
class BaseException
{
public:

    BaseException(string _message)
    : m_message(message)
    {
    }

    string GetErrorMessage() const
    {
        return m_message;
    }

protected:
    string m_message;
};


class Win32Exception : public BaseException
{
public:
    Win32Exception(string operation, int errCode, string sAdditionalInfo = "")
    : BaseException("")

    {
        string message = "";
        message += "Operation \"" + operation + "\" failed with error code ";
        message += std::to_string(errCode);

        if (!sAdditionalInfo.empty())
            message += "\nAdditional info: " + sAdditionalInfo;

        m_message = message;
     }
};
```

Comment: so it's not possible to call a base constructor in the body of a derived class' constructor? only in the inialializer list?